# gl.h included before glew.h

Tags: c++, opengl, dll

I'm trying to use opengl library in my main file. when I compiled it, an error message occurs that "gl.h is included before glew.h"

Firstly, I checked the build messages which file is including gl.h before including glew.h.
As a result, I found qopenglbuffer.h is including gl.h and it is included before including glew.h
But qopenglbuffer.h is library files.

Secondly, I added glew.h at forced include file list but it's not working.

I don't know how to fix this problem but I will keep trying to fix it.
Does someone Know how to fix this issue?

Comment: You should really provide a [mcve].  Having said that, if you are using Qt's OpenGL classes then you really shouldn't need glew.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's a library file"? Just include glew.h before including qopenglbuffer.h. It doesn't matter where the header files are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using Qt's OpenGL support you don't need GLEW.
See [`QOpenGLContext::versionFunctions`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#versionFunctions-1) and [`QOpenGLContext::extraFunctions`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#extraFunctions) to access OpenGL functions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the problem. it caused included header file order.
I have used precompiled header to manage header files easily.
so, I included glew.h before gl.w in my precompiled header thank your comments were really helpful. :)